# Call NodeJs API with Angular2 app

Tags: node.js, angular

For a Project i need to make an app with Angular in which I have to get data from database. So I made an API with NodeJs to handle the connection and to get my data.

but now to call this API with my Angular App there is a problem, I show you my code first

**Here the component in which I try to return my data to use it : (something.component.ts)**

```
onGetData(){
  this.foncService.getData()
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  },(error) => {
    console.log("error : ", error);
  });  
}
```

**Here I call my API : (something.service.ts)**

```
getData(){
  return this.httpClient.get('localhost:3000/api/data').map(res => res);
}
```

**Here I get the data from the database in my API : (api.js)**

```
function getAllDatas(req, res, next) {
  db.any('select * from dat')
  .then(function (data) {
    res.status(200)
    .json({
      status: 'success',
      data: data,
      message: 'done'
    });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    return next(err);
  });
}
```

The API Works well, when I use it alone I get the right data.

Well, the problem is on the component when I want to use my data, so maybe the problem come from my service, idk :(, and so my error is as follow :

[image]

When I want to search about this error on internet I always fall into the CORS problem but I think I have configure it

**api.js**

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())

//or I also tried

app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
});
```

Comment: Assuming that your application is still in under development, Instead of tweaking your code for `CORS`, just download a add-on called `CORS Toggle` in google chrome and once added to your browser, click it and it will turn into green, Then all these `CORS` related issues won't occur until you click it again.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that seems like CORS issue, the way you solved it is 1 method, another one was to use a proxy.config.json file from angular, which re-writes all incoming requests to the proxied port. So instead of 4200, you would re-rewrite to your backend port.

Then you would `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Such as:

https://itnext.io/angular-cli-proxy-configuration-4311acec9d6f

Colors im not sure about, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, now that I have done this proxy config, when I redirect to a path, how can I get my datas from the database please ? 
And is my way to go to the path is good, I use the router.navigate.